# Loss function and batch size in Keras

Tags: keras, tf.keras, loss-function

For classification task there are several loss-function we can use.
If I simply use something like

```
model.compile{ loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy, ....
```

Does this mean loss is normalized in batch size? like

```
loss = 1/m * sum_i sum_c [ y_i^c * ln(y^_i)^c ]
```

wehre m is batch size, and
i  is an index of a sample
c  is class

or the loss is summed up in the batch size?

```
loss = sum_i  sum_c  [ y_i^c * ln(y^_i)^c ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I can find from the keras API docs is that the default reduction for batch optimization is set to `AUTO` which defaults "for almost all cases" to `SUM_OVER_BATCH_SIZE`. This will mean the loss is the scalar sum divided by number of elements in batch.

- [Link for tf.keras.losses](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/CategoricalCrossentropy)
- [Link for tf.keras.losses.Reduction](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/Reduction)

Comment: I see,  "the loss is the scalar sum divided by number of elements in batch", I understand. and Thanks for the link to information which is very useful.